# Why do I keep getting an error about 'operations possible only for numeric, logical or complex types' when creating a bar graph in R using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggpubr

I continually get
`Error in !is.null(facet.by) | combine :  operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types`
when I try and run the following bar graph, I'm super new to both Coding and R and I'm not sure what's causing it.

```
ggbarplot(survival, x = "Treat", y = "Surv",
+ add = c("mean_sd", "jitter"),
+ color = "black",
+ fill = "Treat", palette = "Set3",
+ expand_limits(x=0, y=0),
+ coord_cartesian(expand=FALSE)
+ )
```

I've looked around online but the examples given are most often very specific or the code involved is order of magnitude more complex that this little thing I have.

I was trying to 'use the `expand_limits` function to make the x and y axis start at 0 but after adding the following it errors

```
+ expand_limits(x=0, y=0),
+ coord_cartesian(expand=FALSE)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a formatting issue here, or the code you've actually written but you don't want `+` symbols in an argument to a function. Can you also make your example reproducible by sharing your data (ideally using `dput()`)?

Answer (score 0):

You are actually using `ggpubr` and trying to use `ggplot2` functions in a `ggpubr` function call. Technically it should work when you add those to the `ggbarplot()` result instead:

```
ggbarplot(survival, x = "Treat", y = "Surv",
  add = c("mean_sd", "jitter"),
  color = "black",
  fill = "Treat", palette = "Set3") + 
  expand_limits(x=0, y=0) +
  coord_cartesian(expand=FALSE)
```

Logic here is that `ggbarplot()` returns ggplot object which can further be modified through ggplot methods, but using those in a function itself will not work. All accepted parameters for`ggbarplot()` are listed in https://rpkgs.datanovia.com/ggpubr/reference/ggbarplot.html & https://rpkgs.datanovia.com/ggpubr/reference/ggpar.html .